# How do I install Matlab?

Tags: 11.10, installation, matlab

I have one problem so please help me. I have Ubuntu 11.10 and want to install Matlab; I searched a lot in internet but have not found the exact way yet. Please help me guys, I need it very much.

I know command line, but I don't know what kind of command I should use; I have installed  32 bit library ia32-libs, so what is additionally necessary?

Comment: please update your post with what version of matlab are you trying to install ??? did you get any error ??

Comment: nearest version i want,and i have not started instalation because dont know  what to do

Comment: why did you removed  answer?

Comment: There is a simple set of steps for Ubuntu. Not sure how you've missed it.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB

Comment: problem is that i have not cd for matlab(linux version)i want to download it from terminal

Comment: Free alternatives include ADMB, Euler, FreeMat, Genius, GNU Octave, gretl, R, Sage and Scilab.

Comment: What do you mean you want to download it from terminal? As I remember installing the matlab is strait forward, just run the install script and it works. Could you give some more details?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, then please flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any details you have).

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to obtain a MATLAB install cd, unfortunately. Apart from a small selection of codecs and plugins, there are no licensed applications (that I know of) in the ubuntu repositories. There are a couple of paid applications in the Software Centre, but I checked and MATLAB isn't there.

You can either download a trial from [www.mathworks.com](http://mathworks.com) and use that until you can obtain a full version, or you can try using spyder, which is an open-source matlab-like python IDE, available on the repositories.

Also, don't bother with wine (I can't comment on other people's answers because I don't have the reputation yet). You'll run into exactly the same problem of needing an install cd.

Comment: Just to add that besides Python + NumPy (which I prefer also) there is also Octave which is highly compatible with Matlab. Without GUI at the moment unfortunatelly

Answer (score 0):

While I've used Matlab at university on a Linux terminal, at home I used **Octave** much more often. The code is very similar between the two and *.m files work almost interchangeably between the two. There are a few of the more obscure functions or Matlab which aren't supported but by and large is works very well.

Octave also has a much smaller memory footprint and so can run much smoother on a laptop, or other resource constrained machine.

You can find it in the Ubuntu Software Centre, and for more details visit [the octave project website](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried wine?
you will find it in Ubuntu software center
     or
in terminal  `sudo apt-get install wine`

Comment: and can i install matlab using wine?

Comment: mmm i have never tried to install it on Ubuntu (so i don't know) but after installing wine it can be installed like windows by double click on the install icon

Comment: There is a matlab version native to Linux, buying a windows licence would be very wrong.